# How to debug a class library that is not a dependency of the main C# application (in Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I have a solution where I load some dlls at runtime with Assembly.LoadFile. Because these dlls can come from multiple sources at any time, I cannot add them as a dependency to the main application. It seems that Visual Studio won't load pdb files for dlls that are not marked as a dependency.

I don't want to add each dll I'm debugging to the dependencies just to debug them. Is there a way to manually load symbols for these external dlls?

Comment: Never use LoadFile, always LoadFrom.  Use Debug > Windows > Modules to troubleshoot PDB resolution problems.  Right-click the assembly in the list and select "Symbol Load Information".  Check the "User Code" column, you don't like "no".

Comment: The external assembly is not listed in Modules

Comment: You can't start debugging until it is loaded.  If you're sure that was supposed to have happened then watch out for try/catch-em-all code.  The Output window shows DLL loads and first chance exception notifications.

Comment: After doing the accepted answer it works, the assembly appears in Modules (even if it is not set as startup project). I'm not sure what was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the (plugin) assembly as startup project and in the properties screen at the Debug tab, you can change the **start action**. 
Change it to "Start external program" and select the main project assembly(exe).

When you copied the output of the plugin to the main projects output by hand, you have to change the output path in the Build tab, so the plugin comes in the right path to be loaded by the main program.

Comment: It works! It still shows that no symbols have loaded, but once it loads the dll (when first used) it loads the pdb file, too.

Answer (score -1):

Use reflection. Use methods without creating objects.